# three.js project won't upload a background image on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, three.js, exif

Please see my project:

http://webgl.unilimes.com/project/3dhouse/

On desktop, images are uploaded fine using the camera button:
[image]

However, unfortunately, on IOS this is not the case:

[image]

the image is cropped, there's lots of weird lines across it and it in no way represents the background image uploaded. Furthermore, the desktop app successfully reads the images EXIF data and moves the model accordingly, whilst IOS does not

here are two example images

[Picture of the scene](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9IyIJcyctDfSE5ORkphdjFOMGM/view?usp=sharing).

[Picture for location](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9IyIJcyctDfSmRLMlVuLUo2TFE/view?usp=sharing)

Any pointers as to what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated. I've seen background imagery uploaded with three.js on IOS before, so im hoping there is a solution, as for the [exif reader](http://github.com/mattiasw/exifreader) I don't know. Thanks

Comment: which version of iOS safari are you using?

Comment: iOS 8.3 the latest one!